# Using ntheorem with beamer?

Tags: beamer, ntheorem

I am trying to prepare a mathematical presentation using LaTeX's `beamer` class. Since I already have an `article` on the subject, I want to copy various parts of it into the presentation, in particular various `ntheorem`-environments. But even in the MWE below, this seems not possible. Is there some incompatibility between `ntheorem` and the `beamer` class?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Frankfurt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{Def}
        blabla
    \end{Def}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example brings the error:

```
! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.
```

Explanation: `beamer` provides a theorem environment, just as `ntheorem`, and they provide a style with the same name `plain`. The name colission causes that error.

You can undefine the `plain` style before loading `ntheorem` and the error goes away:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\th@plain\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the job for the MWE. Is there any way to see what is pre-defined by beamer or a way to deactivate it all?

Comment: @Meneldur beamer documentation ;-) otherwise just deactivate what you notice in an error message or warning.