# How to use ntheorem and beamer together?

Tags: beamer, ntheorem

I want to create a presentation with `beamer`. In it I want to include the package `ntheorem`.
When I do it, I get the following error message:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: \begin{altenv} on input line 40 ended by \end{itemize}.
```

It seems to be a known problem since I found some related questions ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167385/using-ntheorem-with-beamer?rq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309387/ntheorem-in-beamer-has-a-problem-with-alert-commands)). However, I tried to include some solution in my MWE, but it is not working.
It also seems that this issue was not present in TeXLive 2019 (whithout any warranty), because I get a problem with `ntheorem` when I recompiled a presentation using it that I made last year.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{amsmath}                    
    \usepackage{amssymb, amscd, amsxtra}
    
        \makeatletter   % Releash command of ntheorem already defined by beamer to avoid conflict
            \let\th@plain\relax 
            \let\openbox\relax 
            \let\proofname\relax 
            \let\proof\relax 
            \let\endproof\relax
        \makeatother    
    \usepackage[amsthm, amsmath, thmmarks, hyperref]{ntheorem}
%       \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
        \newtheorem{defs}{Definition}
    \usepackage[ntheorem]{empheq}

    
    \title{Test}
    \date{\today}
    \author{John Doe}
    \institute{My Institut}


\begin{document}

        \begin{frame}
            \titlepage  
        \end{frame}
        
        \begin{frame}{Animation}
            \begin{itemize}[<+- | alert@+>]
                \item \alert<4>{This is\only<4>{ really} important}
                \item Now this
                \item And now this
            \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}
        
        \begin{frame}{Math}
            \begin{equation}
                e = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n
            \end{equation}
            
            \begin{theorem}[test]
                something
            \end{theorem}
        \end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

So how to solve this problem and use `ntheorem` with `beamer` ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[amsthm]` option of `ntheorem`?

Comment: @Bernard I get the same error message.

Comment: What about `\documentclass[notheorems, noamsthm]{beamer}` to turn off its theorem environments?

Comment: @Davislor, It sounds clever, if I `\documentclass[notheorems, noamsthm]{beamer}` then I redefine the theorem with `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`. But unfortunately I also get the same error message...

Comment: @R.N Posted a MWE that works for me in TeX Live 2020.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to turn off the theorem definitions of `beamer`, or else use those instead of `ntheorem`.

```
\documentclass[notheorems,noamsthm]{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage{amsmath}                    
    \usepackage{amssymb, amscd, amsxtra}

    \usepackage[amsthm, amsmath, thmmarks, hyperref]{ntheorem}
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
      \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
      \newtheorem{defs}{Definition}
    \usepackage[ntheorem]{empheq}

    
    \title{Test}
    \date{\today}
    \author{John Doe}
    \institute{My Institut}


\begin{document}

        \begin{frame}
            \titlepage  
        \end{frame}
        
        \begin{frame}{Animation}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \alert<4>{This is\only<4>{ really} important}
                \item Now this
                \item And now this
            \end{itemize}
        \end{frame}
        
        \begin{frame}{Math}
            \begin{equation}
                e = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n
            \end{equation}
            
            \begin{theorem}[test]
                something
            \end{theorem}
        \end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

I slightly edited the `itemize` command you used to avoid a clash with the option you gave it and the default inner theme.  You’d want to fix that quick-and-dirty kludge, but it’s not germane to your question.

Comment: Your solution seems to solve the problem. Thanks. However, do you know why the initial `itemize` option is clashing ?

Comment: @R.N I haven’t investigated (other than that an inner theme is probably redefining `itemize` in a way that breaks it). I just deleted it to get the MWE to comiple.